# hide("slow") function is not properly working in a AngularJS?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm using jQuery hide function for remove the card with hide("slow") function but hide effect only applies in the last element. It doesn't apply on the first elements. Please sir tell me what's the problem in my code?

```
$(event.currentTarget).parents("#hideAfterRemove").hide("slow");
```

Comment: Is like #hideAfterRemove is duplicated right? Use a class because ID#hideAfterRemove gonna give errors. An ID cant be duplicated.

Comment: Why you are using jquery to hide the domelement. why not `ng-if` or `ng-hide`

Comment: Just FYI `parents("#hideAfterRemove")` is redundant. There should be only 1 element in the DOM with that ID, so you can just do: `$("#hideAfterRemove").hide("slow")`. If there are multiple elements with that `id`, then you need to fix that problem ASAP

Comment: sir i have to remove products  with effects that's the reason i am using jquery?

Comment: @kapilsoni use ng-animate for effects.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sir which place this id is put for remove?

Comment: @ved ok sir i will  try

Answer (score 0):

Use class instead of id because in one DOM there should be unique IDs. If you use same ID multiple times in one DOM, it will always consider 1st ID from top of the DOM.

So attach a class instead then use `fadeOut` instead `hide('slow')`.

```
$('.class').fadeOut('slow');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do in angularjs using model as it two way binding. When this event occurs set the model value to false/true as per your condition.

In DOM set ng-show/ng-if=model.

If you have to use jQuery as a must solution than look into the depth using console or debugger. If your selector is correct than it should work.